# How to plot multiple plots separately?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

**X** Dataset:

```
x = [1.02, .95, .87, .77, .67, .56, .44, .30,
.16, .01, 1.02, .95, .87, .77, .67, .56, .44,
.30, .16, .01, 1.02, .95, .87, .77, .67, .56,
.44, .30, .16, .01, ...................]
```

**Y** Dataset:

```
y = [0.39, .32, .27, .22, .18, .15, .13, .12,
.13, .15, 0.56, .37, .67, .27, .15, .13, .12,
.09, .06, .03,....................................]
```

I have this kind of data where x is repeating after 10 values and y is changing accordingly. I want to plot this data in one graph. I tried this:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

and get the following plot:
[image]

But in this graph, the last point of one graph is connected to the first point of the next graph. I want to separate them.
I want to plot like this:

[image]

Comment: You will need to break x and y into their respective parts, if I understand correctly, `x` and `y` currently have 100 values each and you want to plot every ten separately. Something like `for i in range(10): plt.plot(x[:10], y[10*i:10*(i+1)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the x values by 10's, and then use slicing to plot each x repeat accordingly.

```
for i in range(1, len(x) // 10 + 1):
    plt.plot(x[(i - 1) * 10:i * 10], y[(i - 1) * 10:i * 10])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why add 1 in `range` function just to subtract it later? Should just be `range(len(x) // 10)` and `plt.plot(x[10*i:10*(i+1)], y[10*i:10*(i+1)])`

Comment: or `range(0,len(x),10)` and do less math.

Comment: How to add legend in this plot?